# The "abstract" header has weird numbering

Tags: abstract

[image: Abstract numbering is weird]

Here's  the  MWE. The  abstract numbering  does this  weird numbering where "2" is  embedded into the  number "1". I want the abstract to be un-numbered. Please help me  troubleshoot this. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0.75in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.50in,rmargin=1in}
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}
\date{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{caption} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables



\newpage


\clearpage 
\pagenumbering{Arabic}

\begin{abstract}

*Abstract  text*
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: I get no number if I close with \end{document} and compile

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am compiling in this order- PDFLaTeX-Biber-PDFLaTeX(twice). Should I just use quick build? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Did you try exactly your code as you show it above or do you only assume that it demonstrates your problem? If the code really shows your problem add the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No I am not  assuming it demonstrates my problem. I have different chapters in the document and each of them has  an abstract. When I made this post I was under the impression every abstract header is  doing this weird numbering when only one  particular one is numbering  it weirdly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer \chapter{Chapter name}
\begin{sidewaysfigure} \\
\includegraphics[width=25cm,Height=20cm]{Framework.jpg}
\caption{title}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{sidewaysfigure}



\begin{Abstract}  \end{abstract} This  is the code preceding the  abstract numbering  error. Am I going  wrong  somewhere here?

Comment: if you want help you must produce an example that we can use for a test. It should be short, it should be complete, it should show the problem, it should compile on my computer.